# TextNow for Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-apps

I was wondering if there was a way to get TextNow (the app, not on textnow.com) on Ubuntu Like through terminal. I don't want to download it wrong or anything, that is why I am asking you guys.

Comment: You can try running it in Wine, but I don't think that'll work.

Comment: You could always do it your self with nativefier if you have the time or someone else could. I will look into it my self as I was needing this on Linux and could not find an actual app, a Wrapper for the website is the next best thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest stable version of Google Chrome and then go to the Web Store and get it. I'm running it through Chrome just fine. When you get it, it will appear in your "Apps" portion of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Anbox is an Android emulator I found that allows running Android Apps on any GNU/Linux operating system. It's available at https://anbox.io/ It's a snap package that installs via an installer script available [here](https://github.com/anbox/anbox-installer/blob/master/installer.sh) that does the heavy lifting for you.

Note that "THIS IS ALPHA LEVEL SOFTWARE. EXPECT INSTABILITY AND BUGS" If that doesn't dissuade you, give it a try and help out by reporting any bugs  [here.](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/new)

Comment: No. *This* is not an answer! Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.

Comment: @user722304 I've edited your answer to the best of my ability in an attempt to get it to meet the [quality requirements](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) of our site. If anything is incorrect or you can improve upon what I've done please [edit] your post further.